# Using IMPORTRANGE with FILTER and ISNUMBER

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, importrange

In one Gsheet, I have a function combining FILTER and ISNUMBER.

```
=FILTER('1.Requests'!B:B,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H1,'1.Requests'!AM:AM)))
```

I need to be able to return multiple values based on a partial match.  It works beautifully for what I need when this function is in the same Gsheet as the information that I want to filter.

However, I also need to be able to use this function with `IMPORTRANGE` so that it can go into a different Gsheet and still work.  In this case, the cell with the search term is B1, rather than H1.  I have tried this:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE URL","'1.Requests'!$B1:B100"),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE URL",'1.Requests'!$AM1:$AM100))))``
```

and this

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE URL","'1.Requests'!$B:B"),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE URL",'1.Requests'!$AM:$AM))))
```

It keeps returning #N/A with this message:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 81. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

Help?!

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to run `IMPORTRANGE` alone and allow access to connect your sheets

```
=IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE URL", "'1.Requests'!$B1")
```

only then you can use your complex formula